# UNIX: excluding patterns, contained in a file, from another file with grep

Tags: grep

I have a txt file that contains the patterns I would like to exclude from a file. Is there a way to chain `grep -f` and `grep -v`?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can use the options together like:

```
grep -vf exclude.txt file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat exclude.txt 
3

$ cat file.txt
1
3
4
1
4
3
1
2

$ grep -vf exclude.txt file.txt 
1
4
1
4
1
2
```

Comment: Thanks! However, grep does not seem to filtering based on exclude.txt - Would there be a problem with the exclude.txt?

Comment: @NicholasHayden Thats the way to go. If you have any problem then it must be with the patterns.

Comment: @NicholasHayden, you might want to check out the `-x` and `-F` options in `man grep`.